How to get .obj or .stl format 3D mesh from .fm format raw data (scan streams) of the scanner?
I have extracted the raw data from the dental intraoral scanner in .fm format. Is there a way to open it and export it as .stl or .obj?
If possible, any software/plugin/script recommedation?
Rescan is not possible since I don't have the scanned object anymore.
